# RegawMOD adb shell su privileges issue

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, shell, adb

I'm currently building a c# windows app that has a requirement of emptying out the sms inbox from an android devices.

I'm using RegawMOD.android lib to create and execute `adb` commands.

The first thought was to delete `mmssms.db` and reboot the device which works.

However, rebooting the device takes a lot of time.

so I took another approach :

- I copied the DB to the internal SD card
- pulled it to my pc
- accessed it with `sqlite` (through code) and emptied the SMS table.
- copied it back to internal SD card.

The problem is with copying it back to `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/`

When I try to run it inside the code, I get *permission denied* even though I run it with shell and `su` settings. If I run the same code in `adb shell` on a command line prompt, it works perfectly.

this is the code :

```
AdbCommand MoveToData = Adb.FormAdbShellCommand(device, true, "cat", "/storage/sdcard0/download/mmssms.db > /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `su 0 cat /storage/sdcard0/download/mmssms.db > /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db` command only the part before the redirection runs with `root` privileges. The redirection is still being run with your app's user ID.